# Return from a function decorator with class as decorator

Tags: python, class, oop, decorator

Here is my piece of code (Python 3.9.2)

```
class My_style:
    #self.fn = fn
    #fn= greet()
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s = s
    def __call__(self,fn):
        self.fn = fn()
        if self.s == "upper":
            return self.fn.upper()
        elif self.s == "bold":
            return "<b>" + self.fn +  "</b>"
#@My_style("bold")
def greet():
    return "Hello World"
```

```
decorator = My_style("upper")
greet = decorator(greet)  ## This returns the string object instead of function object greet()
greet
'HELLO WORLD'
```

what you get as a return is not function greet() but a string as greet.
I am not able to understand why it is returning a string.

I was expecting the above output with greet()

So the above decorator works perfectly fine if I just say greet (as a string) but I was expecting it to work is greet() (Function call)

What am I missing?

Added where it returns a function without decorator wrapper as return as mentioned in the answer (But it is not parametrized to select between "upper" or "bold")

```
class ToUpper:
    def __init__(self, fn): # Decorator
        self.fn = fn
    
    def __call__(self):  # Wrapper
        return self.fn().upper()

def greet():  
    return "Hello world"
```

```
greet = ToUpper(greet) # This returns greet() instead of string
greet()
'HELLO WORLD'
```

Probably parametrized call necessitates it to return the function (in **call** method) explicitly?

Comment: Well, when do you expect `__init__` to be called? What do you expect it to be called with? When do you expect `__call__` to be called? What do you expect it to be called with? What do you expect it to return?

Comment: [This question](/questions/739654/how-to-make-function-decorators-and-chain-them-together) is not a duplicate per se; but it contains some of the most comprehensive overall explanations of how decorators work that I've ever seen, on or off Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to understand what goes on if we rewrite

```
@My_style("bold")
def greet():
    return "Hello World"
```

without the decorator syntactic sugar:

```
def greet():
    return "Hello World"

decorator = My_style("bold")
greet = decorator(greet)
```

You can see that the first step is to create the callable decorator (`__init__` gets executed at that time).

Then we call this decorator. That's when `__call__` gets executed, and it is supposed to return the new decorated function, to which we'll give the name of the original one (`greet`). The decorator has done its job now, and won't be involved in anything anymore.

Calling `greet` then calls this decorated function (and not the `__call__` method of the decorator!).

So, the updated version of the code, where `__call__` creates and returns the decorated function:

```
class My_style:
    #self.fn = fn
    #fn= greet()
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s = s
    
    def __call__(self,fn):
        def decorated():
            if self.s == "upper":
                return fn().upper()
            elif self.s == "bold":
                return "<b>" + fn() +  "</b>"
        return decorated    
        
@My_style("bold")
def greet():
    return "Hello World"

greet()
# '<b>Hello World</b>'

@My_style("upper")
def shout():
    return "Hello World"

shout()
# 'HELLO WORLD'
```

Comment: "Calling greet then calls this decorated function" After fixing it, yes. In OP's case, it attempts to call the *string* that resulted from the decoration, raising an exception.

Comment: As I understand, this is about returning a function vs string from the class __call__ method. My code was returning a string object for greet = decorator(greet) while with the wrapper return (decorated) gives the same as greet().(function object). When Class instance is not parametrized, it does return the function  though in actuality you are returning the string. Please check my edited question. Thanks for the answer